# Laravel Eloquent Query WhereHas

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire, eloquent-relationship, has-one

I have the following code for reference

//MODEL_A

```
public function latest_B()
{
return $this->hasOne(B::class)->latest();
}
 public function Bs()
{
return $this->hasMany(B::class);
}
```

//Livewire

```
return A::where(function ($q1) {
            $q1->where('id',auth()->user()->id)
           ->orWhere('for',auth()->user()->email);
        })
        ->whereYear('created_at',$this->year)
        ->orWhereHas('latest_B',function($q2){
            $q2->where('att_for',auth()->user()->email)
            ->orWhere('tta_for',auth()->user()->id)
            ;
        })
        ->search($this->search)
        ->latest()
        ->paginate($this->perPage);
```

My problem is this query still returning model  A with NOT latest model B .

I am expecting only to get 3 result, but it is returning 7.

Comment: Can you show us a sample data of Table-A and Table-B?

Comment: You can also use ->dd() to debug the query... temporarily replace paginate with 
->dd() and show us the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your model Function `latest_b` are you using that to get the latest item of B::class? If so then you can use Laravel's `Has One Of Many` Feature

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many

```php
public function latest_b(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(B::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

I don't really know your the data structure you have and the output of the query but if I understand your issue properly... try using this...

if you can provide an answer to my comments above I will be able to give you a much more clear answer.

```php
return A::query()->whereYear('created_at',$this->year)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($q1) {
            $q1->where('id',auth()->user()->id)->orWhere('for',auth()->user()->email);
        })->orWhereHas('latest_B',function($q2){
            $q2->where('att_for',auth()->user()->email)->orWhere('tta_for',auth()->user()->id);
        })
    })
    ->search($this->search)
    ->latest()
    ->paginate($this->perPage);
```

Comment: This solve my problem! latestOfMany() havent really tried to read the full documentation of Laravel 10 since last time i used it way back to 5 & 6.